# Errores con Zend/Translate.php

Tags: php, xampp, macos, zend

Zend Framework me muestra errores, los servicios que tengo para el servidor local son: xampp (MySql y Apache) en Mac High Sierra.

> Warning: include(Zend/Translate.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tnw/library/Zend/Loader.php on
>   line 83
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Translate.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tnw/library:.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php')
>   in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tnw/library/Zend/Loader.php
>   on line 83
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Translate' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tnw/application/Bootstrap.php on
>   line 50

Comment: ¿Estás usando la versión 1 de Zend Framework? ¿Cómo estás instanciando a Zend Translate en Bootstrap.php?

Comment: Gracias Oscar, es versión 2.5 y te dejo el código justo en la línea que me marca el error. Si necesitas toda la función me avisas por favor.   $translate = new Zend_Translate('array', $translationFile, $lang, array('disableNotices'=>false));

Comment: Es que tanto `./application/Bootstrap.php` como  `Zend_Translate` son configuración de la versión 1. En la version 2 se llama a través del _serviceManager_ o _serviceLocator_ con el alias _ translator_.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, efectivamente se llama a través de serviceLocator, pero hasta donde entendí eso lo hace con el Zend Server. Agradezco tu tiempo y apoyo, compartí la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución. Coloqué los archivos faltantes dentro de la carpeta Zend. Esos archivos faltan debido a que no estaba usando Zend Server. Por ello es que el Bootstrap.php tampoco los encontraba. Le otorgué permisos de escritura la carpeta caché, que está dentro de applications/data.

Comment: Enhorabuena entonces, mejor que sea eso a un problema de configuración. Suerte y cualquier cosa, por aquí estamos. Saludos.